# Tracking outbound links with Google Tag Manager without hurting SEO

Tags: seo, google-analytics, googlebot, links, google-tag-manager

My website contains a widget with links to social media and I'm using a script to open the links.

Because I'm not adding the links directly into `href` attribute I think the web crawlers may be missing them and that may be hurting my SEO.

I want each of the outbound link clicks to be tracked besides just navigating to the URL.

How should I set this up with Google Tag Manager?

Widget HTML:

```
<ul class="social-networks">
    <li>
        <a 
            href="javascript:void(0);" 
            onclick="navigate('pinterest');"
        >Pinterest</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a 
            href="javascript:void(0);" 
            onclick="navigate('facebook');"
        >Facebook</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a 
            href="javascript:void(0);" 
            onclick="navigate('instagram');"
        >Instagram</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

JS (Google Tag Manager):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  function trackOutboundLink(name, url) {
     dataLayer.push( {
        'event': 'Navigation Click',
        'navigationClick': {
          'name': name,
          'url': url
        }
      });
  }

  function navigate(name) {

    let url;

    if (name==='facebook') {
        url = 'https://www.facebook.com/MyAccount'; 
    } else if (name==='instagram') {
        url = 'https://www.instagram.com/MyAccount';  
    } else if (name==='pinterest') {
        url = 'https://www.pinterest.com/MyAccount/';  
    } else {
        console.log('Warning: Unknown link'); 
    }

    trackOutboundLink(name, url);
    window.open(url);
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution by using `onclick` to track the click and `href` to navigate. Even simpler seems to use the Google Tag Manager's outbound link tracking trigger, which seems to eliminate the need for `onclick` script completely.

Widget HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a 
            href="https://www.pinterest.com/MyAccount/" 
            onclick="return trackOutboundLink('pinterest');"
        >Pinterest</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a 
            href="https://www.facebook.com/MyAccount" 
            onclick="return trackOutboundLink('facebook');"
        >Facebook</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a 
            href="https://www.instagram.com/MyAccount" 
            onclick="return trackOutboundLink('instagram');"
        >Instagram</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

JS (Google Tag Manager):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  function trackOutboundLink(name) {
     dataLayer.push( {
        'event': 'Navigation Click',
        'navigationClick': {
          'name': name
        }
      });
      return true;
  }
</script>
```